# JPA, JBoss, Hibernate, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to setup a simple project, where I have a REST service query a database using JPA/Hibernate. My platform is Windows, MySQL 5.6, and JBoss (Wildfly) 8 with hibernate 4.3. My project setup:

PersonApp (Eclipse Java Enterprise Project) >PersonApp.ear
-PersonData (Eclipse JPA Project) >PersonData.jar
-PersonRest (Eclipse Dynamic Web Project) >PersonRest.war

PersonData project contains 1 entity class (Person.java), a manager class for peforming the em.find and em.persist through EntityManager (PersonManager.java), and persistance.xml

PersonRest project contains one REST service, with one GET method, which calls the PersonManager class to query all Persons.

PersonApp is just a container project which includes PersonData and PersonRest as modules.

**Now for the issue**: I deploy PersonApp.ear to Wildfly 8 (JBoss), and navigate to the service URL in a web browser. PersonRest service calls PersonManager class, which calls Persistence.createEntityManagerFactor("PersonData"); This line returns 'null' and I have no idea why.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PersonData" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.csc.data.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Wildfly startup output (shows app deployment, data source loaded, persistence unit):

```
14:31:14,607 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
14:31:14,841 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Final
14:31:14,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" starting
14:31:15,871 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found PersonApp.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called PersonApp.ear.dodeploy
14:31:15,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
14:31:15,903 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.2.0.Final
14:31:15,919 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
14:31:15,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
14:31:15,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
14:31:15,966 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
14:31:15,997 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
14:31:15,997 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
14:31:15,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.20.Final
14:31:15,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
14:31:15,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
14:31:16,028 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.3.Final)
14:31:16,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
14:31:16,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
14:31:16,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
14:31:16,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:31:16,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
14:31:16,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = com.mysql
14:31:16,184 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Final/welcome-content
14:31:16,200 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
14:31:16,434 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
14:31:16,543 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
14:31:16,605 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
14:31:16,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS]
14:31:16,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "PersonApp.ear" (runtime-name: "PersonApp.ear")
14:31:16,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
14:31:16,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
14:31:16,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "PersonRest.war")
14:31:16,855 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final
14:31:16,870 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for PersonData
14:31:16,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'PersonApp.ear#PersonData'
14:31:16,948 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: PersonData
    ...]
14:31:16,996 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
14:31:17,012 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
14:31:17,012 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
14:31:17,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'PersonApp.ear#PersonData'
14:31:17,277 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
14:31:17,511 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
14:31:17,589 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
14:31:17,620 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
14:31:17,885 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
14:31:17,932 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) HHH000230: Schema export complete
14:31:18,197 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.csc.rest.service.PersonRest
14:31:18,197 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Adding singleton resource com.csc.rest.service.PersonService from Application class com.csc.rest.service.PersonRest
14:31:18,323 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017534: Registered web context: /PersonRest
14:31:18,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "PersonApp.ear" (runtime-name : "PersonApp.ear")
14:31:18,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
14:31:18,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
14:31:18,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started in 4059ms - Started 291 of 351 services (98 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Wildfly output on REST service call:

```
14:32:06,221 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: PersonData
    ...]
14:32:06,236 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-2) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
14:32:06,236 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (default task-2) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
14:32:06,252 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (default task-2) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
14:32:06,268 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (default task-2) HHH000230: Schema export complete
14:32:06,300 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /PersonRest/PersonService: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at com.csc.data.PersonManager.openConnection(PersonManager.java:51) [PersonData.jar:]
    at com.csc.rest.service.PersonService.getAllPersons(PersonService.java:21) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    ... 29 more
```

It looks like Wildfly is able to find persistance.xml, and it is able to connect to the MySQL database (it even drops the table data as expected). It shows in the output that it found the persistence unit PersonData. I even tried changing the provider to something off the wall just to see if it would error. It did error saying it couldn't find the provider class.  I changed it back and the error went away, so I assume it is able to find the provider.  What am I missing?

Comment: where is your mysql connection parameters in `persistence.xml`??

Comment: The database connection is configured in JBoss as a datasource "java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. Did you click the `Test Connection` from your `connection` at that `datasource` in JBoss console? Is that returned you success message?

Comment: Yep, 'Test Connection' returns "Successfully created JDBC Connection. Successfully connected to database MySqlDS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my REST service, I was instantiating the PersonManager class myself.  Instead, I needed to inject it with @Inject.  After this, it worked, almost.  I then had a problem getting CDI to work inside a RESTeasy REST service, but that was a separate issue.  More details can be found here in my JBoss community thread: https://community.jboss.org/message/863014#863014